# Problems with Scala Inheritance

Tags: scala, inheritance

)
I have one Parent class called Mob, and I am creating two subclasses Human and Monster.

```
  abstract class Mob(
                      var name: String,
                      var healthPoints: Int,
                      var attackPower: Int,
                      var defense: Int
                    ) {

    var level: Int = 1
    var isAlive: Boolean = true
    
    val attackBooster: Map[String, Int]

    def attack(opponent: Mob): Unit
    def getSound: String

    def boostAttack(attributes: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
      attributes.map((x: Int) => x + this.attackPower)
    }
  }

class Human(
               override var name: String,
               override var healthPoints: Int,
               override var attackPower: Int,
               override var defense: Int,
               var strength: Int,
               var agility: Int,
               var intelligence: Int,
               var profession: String,
               var kingdom: String
             ) extends Mob(
    name: String,
    healthPoints: Int,
    attackPower: Int,
    defense: Int
  ) {

    def this(
              name: String,
              healthPoints: Int,
              attackPower: Int,
              defense: Int,
              strength: Int,
              agility: Int,
              intelligence: Int,
              profession: String = "",
              kingdom: String = ""
            ) {
      this(name, healthPoints, attackPower, defense, strength, agility, intelligence, profession, kingdom)
      this.profession = chooseProfession(profession)
      this.kingdom = chooseKingdom(kingdom)
    }

class Monster(
                 override var name: String,
                 override var healthPoints: Int,
                 override var attackPower: Int,
                 override var defense: Int,
                 var toxicity: Int,
                 var brutality: Int,
                 var confusion: Int,
                 var curse: Int,
                 var kind: String
               ) extends Mob(
    name: String,
    healthPoints: Int,
    attackPower: Int,
    defense: Int
  ) {

    def this(
              name: String,
              healthPoints: Int,
              attackPower: Int,
              defense: Int,
              toxicity: Int,
              brutality: Int,
              confusion: Int,
              curse: Int,
              kind: String = ""
            ) {
      this(name, healthPoints, attackPower, defense, toxicity, brutality, confusion, curse, kind)
      this.kind = chooseKind(kind)
    }
```

The problems regarding this inheritance is that:

- I cannot overload the default constructor (Constructor is defined twice and ambiguous reference to overloaded definition)
- I cannot overload mutable members of the parent Mob class

I am new to Scala, and unfortunately I could not find any solution regarding my issue. Could you please clarify what the problem is and how I can solve it?

Comment: Well, your constructor _is_ defined twice. Not sure what you are trying to do there. Just remove the second definition. 
As for mutable members ... DON'T. If you are going to learn to use scala, you might as well do it right. You don't need those members to be mutable (also don't need to override them actually). Just pretend that `var` does not exist. Trust me, you won't miss it.

Comment: @Dima I wanted to include the constructor in which the Human.kingdom, profession and Monster.kind are received from other method. That's why the constructors 'are duplicated' in terms of required parameters. And regarding the 'vars', how do I override them or simply define them in the derived class?

Comment: Your second constructor has the same parameters as the first one. If you want some parameters to come from somewhere else, you should remove them from the definition. 
As to the `vars`, like I said: do not use vars. Also, you do not need to override them. They are already defined in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a companion object with those classes, to overload constructor methods:

- [Companion Object](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/companion-objects.html)

Once you have your companion object, you can create as many `apply` methods as you want. `apply` in Scala (inside companion objects) is a syntactic sugar that allows you to create a new instance of your class without the `new` keyword - easier to read constructors (read on when to use companion objects).

Also, as much as you would like to overload the constructor methods with the same parameters, that's just not possible - it's the *same constructor* to Scala. The compiler wouldn't be able to choose which constructor you need to use, so in order to avoid that situation, Scala does not allow you to use the *same* constructor twice. If you change the parameters in any way (type or number of parameters), you'll see that it does allow you to create a second constructor.

Comment: 'value += is not a member of Int', and how can I access the 'var' attributes from parent class?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about `value += is not a member of Int`? That operator is not in your original post.

Comment: Also, about the `var` variables. Your parent class is like a "_cake pan_": you define the shape (parameters or functions); your child classes are the cakes: might be carrot or chocolate cake... if asking for the cake's frosting, you don't ask the pan, you ask the cake. In English, you don't ask the parent class, as is the child class the one who has the information.
**EDIT**: Your parent's attributes are present in your child class: you used your parent to shape your children class. 
You can look it up in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)).